# Combine arrays from observables without waiting for all to complete

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my application I retrieve data from a remote server at a definite interval. Data is formatted as an array of objects and displayed in the HTML template via the angular async pipe.
I am using `shareReplay()` to provide caching functionality:

```js
  private refresherToggleSales$: Subject<void>;
  private displayLastSales$: Observable<Sale[]>;

  public InjectSale$: Subject<Sale[]>;
  
  [...]

   get LastSales() : Observable<Sale[]> {
    if (!this.displayLastSales$) {
      const rTimer$ = timer(0, DefaultRefresh);

      this.displayLastSales$ = rTimer$.pipe(
        switchMap(_ => this.getLastSales()),
        shareReplay(this.CACHE_SIZE),
        takeUntil(this.refresherToggleSales$)
      );
    }

    return merge(this.displayLastSales$, this.InjectSale$);
  }

  private getLastSales() : Observable<Sale[]> {
    // get data from server
  }
```

Whenever a sale is manually input in the application, I would like for it to be displayed immediately without having to wait for it to come from the server.

However if I call `InjectLastSale$.next()` with a 1-element array it will completely replace all previous data.
How can I combine the two streams (without having one to wait on the other to complete)?

Comment: You can use combineLatest Operater 

    combineLatest(this.displayLastSales$, this.InjectSale$).subscribe(
    (displayLastSales, InjectSale) => {
            console.log(displayLastSales, InjectSale )
          })

now whenever data is emited you will see it immediately without waiting for the other observable to emit data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! Just change up where you place your `merge`.

```ts
get LastSales() : Observable<Sale[]> {
    
  if (!this.displayLastSales$) {
    this.displayLastSales$ = timer(0, DefaultRefresh).pipe(
      switchMap(_ => this.getLastSales().pipe(
        mergeWith(this.InjectSale$),
        scan((acc, vals) => [...vals, ...acc], <Sale[]>[])
      )),
      shareReplay(this.CACHE_SIZE),
      takeUntil(this.refresherToggleSales$)
    );
  }

  return this.displayLastSales$;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combineLatest Operater

```
combineLatest(this.displayLastSales$, this.InjectSale$).subscribe(
(displayLastSales, InjectSale) => {
        console.log(displayLastSales, InjectSale )
      })
```

now whenever data is emited you will see it immediately without waiting for the other observable to emit data.

Comment: RXJS documentation states _Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value_ so on app start I would need to manually trigger `InjectLastSale$.next()` or else nothing would ever be displayed